# jquery fade in fade out on hover for multiple elements

Tags: jquery, hover, fadein, fadeout

I am working on a portfolio page and would like to use jquery to fade in some information over the image when the user hovers over the item.

I am quite new to back-end jquery stuff so just starting to get my hands dirty.

I have managed to get the fade in and out to work on a singular div element, but I need it to work independently for each one. I assume this requires some kind more dynamic code, but I'm not sure where to start.

If you look below I have the code which works for one item. The div appears when you hover over the first image. This is the structure I need as the real portfolio has this basic structure. I just need the code to get it working for the other two. There will be multiple hover overs in the live site.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.0/jquery.min.js"     type="text/javascript"></script>
<title>Robs Test</title>
<style>
body{background:gray;}
div{position:relative;}
#box{
    position:relative;
    width:150px;
    height:150px;
    float:left;
    display:block;
    background:black;
    margin-right:20px;
}
#boxover{
    position:absolute;
    top:10px;
    left:0px;
    width:100%;
    height:20px;
    z-index:100;
    background:white;
    display:none;
}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        $('#box').hover(over, out);
    });

function over(event)
{
    $('#boxover').fadeIn(2000);
    $('#boxover').css("display","normal");
}
function out(event)
{
    $('#boxover').fadeOut(2000);
}
</script>

</head>

<body>
<a href="#" id="box"><img src="anyimage.jpg" alt="test" width="150" height="150" /><div id="boxover">hello</div></a>
<a href="#" id="box"><img src="anyimage.jpg" alt="test" width="150" height="150" /><div id="boxover">there</div></a>
<a href="#" id="box"><img src="anyimage.jpg" alt="test" width="150" height="150" /><div id="boxover">rob</div></a>

</body>

</html>
```

If someone could show me how to make each one work independently that would be great.

I'm guessing a rel attribute like lightbox?

I'm happy to give each image a separate id/rel. I just don't want to replicate the css.

Hope that makes sense :)

OK, so I have updated it but it still doesn't work. I can see what is going on, but not sure the exact syntax to get it working.

Here is my new code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.0/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<title>Robs Test</title>
<style>
body{background:gray;}
div{position:relative;}
.box{
    position:relative;
    width:150px;
    height:150px;
    float:left;
    display:block;
    background:black;
    margin-right:20px;
}
.boxover{
    position:absolute;
    top:10px;
    left:0px;
    width:100%;
    height:20px;
    z-index:100;
    background:white;
    display:none;
}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        $('.box').hover(over, out);
    });


    function over(event){
        var over_id = '#box_over_' + $(this).attr('id').replace('over_','');
        $(over_id).fadeIn(2000);
    }, 
    function out(event) {
        var over_id = '#box_over_' + $(this).attr('id').replace('over_','');
        $(over_id).fadeOut(2000);
    }

</script>

</head>

<body>
<a href="#" class="box" id="over_1"><img src="pier.jpg" alt="test" width="150" height="150" /><div id="box_over_1" class="boxover">hello</div></a>
<a href="#" class="box" id="over_2"><img src="pier.jpg" alt="test" width="150" height="150" /><div id="box_over_2" class="boxover">there</div></a>
<a href="#" class="box" id="over_3"><img src="pier.jpg" alt="test" width="150" height="150" /><div id="box_over_3" class="boxover">rob</div></a>


</body>

</html>
```

I think I'm nearly there as the pseudo logic makes sense, but it's still not working.

Cheers

Rob

Answer (score 4):

Here you go:
http://jsfiddle.net/Mm66A/13/

Please don't use ID fields for naming things "box,box,box", use the Class of 'box' to say that each item is of type 'box'. You can give each box a UNIQUE id.

Answer (score 0):

You can't have more than one element with the same `id` in valid html.  Change each `id` to `class` and change your jquery selectors from `$('#box')` and `$('#boxover')` to `$('.box')` and `$('.boxover')` and this should work for you...

Answer (score 0):

First: Don't use the same `id` for all of your `a`s and `div`s. An id is a **unique** identifier of an element, for "groups" of elements there is the `class` attribute.

To get the corresponding box to show/hide, use the advanced selectors of jquery, trying to get the one box which is directly before the hovered element.

Answer (score 0):

You could do:

```
<a href="#" class="box"><img src="anyimage.jpg" alt="test" width="150" height="150" /><div class="boxover">hello</div></a>
<a href="#" class="box"><img src="anyimage.jpg" alt="test" width="150" height="150" /><div class="boxover">there</div></a>
<a href="#" class="box"><img src="anyimage.jpg" alt="test" width="150" height="150" /><div class="boxover">rob</div></a>


$(function() {
    $('.box').hover(over, out);
});

function over(event) {
    $('.boxover', this).fadeIn(2000);
    $('.boxover', this).css("display", "normal");
}

function out(event) {
    $('.boxover', this).fadeOut(2000);
}
```

fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/rynma/

Basically you must use `classes` instead of `ids` because id must be unique and you pass a `context` to the jquery selector to restrict the selection to the context (i use `this`)

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the browsers you're targeting, you [don't need jQuery at all](http://www.w3schools.com/css3/css3_transitions.asp). If you have to target IE and can't suffer the immediate change instead of transitioning, you could conditionally comment a reference to a Javascript for it like the other posters have mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

i would give each a tag a unique id, and give the over box an id of 'over_' + id_of_box_link and change id=box to class=box then you can apply the hover by doing this:

you cannot have duplicate IDs.

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="box" id="over_1"><img src="anyimage.jpg" alt="test" width="150" height="150" /><div id="box_over_1">hello</div></a>
<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="box" id="over_2"><img src="anyimage.jpg" alt="test" width="150" height="150" /><div id="box_over_2">there</div></a>
<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="box" id="over_3"><img src="anyimage.jpg" alt="test" width="150" height="150" /><div id="box_over_3">rob</div></a>



$(".box").hover(
    function () {
        var over_id = '#box_over_' + $(this).attr('id').replace('over_','');
        $(over_id).fadeIn(2000);
    }, 
    function () {
        var over_id = '#box_over_' + $(this).attr('id').replace('over_','');
        $(over_id).fadeOut(2000);
    }
);
```

Comment: Hi,

that seems to make sense. I understand I can't use ID's, it was just for the example :)

I have done what you said, but it doesn't seem to work? Any thoughts?

Thanks :)