# Hover Event for Multiple Paired Navigational Elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, navigation, hover

I'm trying to build a landing page that lists a set of sub-pages in two, separate but PAIRED navigational interfaces.

The first is a text list of the sub-pages, the second is a thumbnail list of the sub-pages. The first item of the text list is paired with the first thumbnail from the thumbnail list.

The HTML looks something like this:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <ul class="nav-list">
        <li><a href="link">Nav Item 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="link">Nav Item 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="link">Nav Item 3</a></li>
        <li><a href="link">Nav Item 4</a></li>
        <li><a href="link">Nav Item 5</a></li>
        <li><a href="link">Nav Item 6</a></li>
        <li><a href="link">Nav Item 7</a></li>
        <li><a href="link">Nav Item 8</a></li>
    </ul>               
<div class="nav-thumb">
    <a href="link"><img width="150" height="80" src="navimage1.jpg" /></a>
    <a href="link"><img width="150" height="80" src="navimage2.jpg" /></a>
    <a href="link"><img width="150" height="80" src="navimage3.jpg" /></a>
    <a href="link"><img width="150" height="80" src="navimage4.jpg" /></a>
    <a href="link"><img width="150" height="80" src="navimage5.jpg" /></a>
    <a href="link"><img width="150" height="80" src="navimage6.jpg" /></a>
    <a href="link"><img width="150" height="80" src="navimage7.jpg" /></a>
    <a href="link"><img width="150" height="80" src="navimage8.jpg" /></a>
</div>
</div>
```

The tricky part (for me) is that the paired elements should have related hover style changes. For example, when a visitor hovers over Nav Item 2, the styles will change for that text list item (a simple text-decoration change) AND the style will change on the paired thumbnail image (opacity will change from 0.5 to 1). Also: if the user hovers over NavImage2, the styles will change both on the image (opacity) and the paired text list item (text-decoration).

I've created a [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Rfrxg/3/) with the coding as I currently have it (hover events work separately, but are not paired in any way) -- to provide a visual example if nothing else.

The only other issue, that I can think of, is that the navigational lists (both text and images) are created dynamically, so I can't hard code specific scripting for the (currently) eight nav items (as it may be 10 or 20, etc. items in the future).

For reference, here are a few of the other solutions I've explored:

[jquery-hover-on-two-separate-elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8739108/jquery-hover-on-two-separate-elements)

[how-to-link-the-hover-effects-of-two-identical-nav-bars](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18307894/how-to-link-the-hover-effects-of-two-identical-nav-bars)

[jquery-fade-in-fade-out-on-hover-for-multiple-elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8578307/jquery-fade-in-fade-out-on-hover-for-multiple-elements)

[jquery-hover-dependent-on-two-elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6132006/jquery-hover-dependent-on-two-elements)

[jquery-non-nested-non-descendant-sibling-navigation-shown-on-hover-event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14946375/jquery-non-nested-non-descendant-sibling-navigation-shown-on-hover-event)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use jquery to add a class "hover" to the element with the same id on the second navigation like this
JS

```
//add .data("pair") to each element in both navigations with the index value
$(".nav-list a").each(function(i,n){
    $(this).data("pair",i);    
});
$(".nav-thumb img").each(function(i,n){
    $(this).data("pair",i);    
});
//index var to use the same data in mouseover and mouseout
var index;
$(".nav-list a").mouseover(function() {
    index=$(this).data("pair");
//select the element assuming both navigations have the same amount of elements
    $(".nav-thumb img").eq(index).addClass("hover");//add class hover
}).mouseout(function() {
    $(".nav-thumb img").eq(index).removeClass("hover");//remove class hover
});
//the same for the second navigation 
$(".nav-thumb img").mouseover(function() {
    index=$(this).data("pair");
    $(".nav-list a").eq(index).addClass("hover");
}).mouseout(function() {
    $(".nav-list a").eq(index).removeClass("hover");
});
```

CSS

```
.nav-list a:hover,.nav-list a.hover { color: #03c; text-decoration: none; }
.wrapper img:hover,.wrapper img.hover { opacity: 1;}
```

you need to change those classes so you can imitate the :hover state with the .hover class
http://jsfiddle.net/Rfrxg/4/

Comment: YES. Absolutely perfect. Thank you so much! I hope that many others will also benefit from your clear and helpful answer.